# Adding photo in QGIS Attribute table and exporting in Excel

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, export, excel, photos

I want to export an attribute table in Excel with photos visible in table but in Excel in QGIS is visible like path-link, but I want to be a photo. Any idea?

[image]